# XPath to get namespace of root node

Tags: xml, xpath

Given the following xml snippets:

```
<ns2:Invoice xmlns="http://defaultnamespace.com" xmlns:ns2="http://namespace2.com"
  xmlns:ns3="http://namespace3.com">
.........
</ns2:Invoice>
```

and:

```
<ns3:Invoice xmlns="http://defaultnamespace.com" xmlns:ns2="http://namespace2.com"
  xmlns:ns3="http://namespace3.com">
.........
</ns3:Invoice>
```

Can xpath be used to get the namespace associated with the root (`<Invoice>`) element?

Expected results would be as follows:
In the first example, the root is prefixed "ns2" so I would expect "http://namespace2.com"
In the second example, the root is prefixed "ns3" so I would expect "http://namespace3.com"

Answer (score 5):

You can use `namespace-uri(/*)`, see http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-namespace-uri.